# Como adicionar imagem como background fixo?

Tags: html, css

Ao invés do comum fundo branco no meu site, ou ao invés de definir outra cor de fundo, quero definir uma imagem como background. Quero essa imagem fixa, sem se movimentar com a rolagem da página e adaptada à tela, preenchendo toda a largura e altura da janela principal. Sobre esse fundo quero colocar um formulário, um banner e demais informações... sempre deixando todo o conteúdo sobre o plano de fundo (imagem). A minha pergunta é: Como faço isso?

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como colocar o efeito de plano de fundo fixo e na tela toda?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/100689/como-colocar-o-efeito-de-plano-de-fundo-fixo-e-na-tela-toda)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tem um modo de se fazer isso apenas com css, essa forma da **suporte apenas para IE 9+**.
Se for uma imagem fixa que ficará pra sempre lá, você pode deixa-la no body (ou na tag "container" do seu site) da seguinte forma:

```
body{
  background: url('sua-imagem.jpg') center center no-repeat fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Utilizando o "cover" do css3, a imagem irá se ajustar automaticamente ao tamanho da sua tela.

Se você precisar dar suporte para navegadores mais antigos, a solução será, através de javascript, pegar o tamanho da tela e setar na div da imagem para saber qual a altura que ela deve ficar.

Answer (score -2):

Para deixar uma imagem de plano de fundo fixo exemplo:

```
body{
    background-image:url("imagens/foto3.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height:2000px;
    background-attachment:fixed;
}
```